# Is there a way in Adobe Illustrator to add Artboard's name into its own content automatically?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard, illustrator-scripting

I want Artboards have their own names in themselves, for example in corner left top.

I just wondered if there is any special character to do it, but there is not!

Maybe a script will do the job!

Answer (score 2):

A script can do the job, but how exactly you wish to best implement would effect the best rendition of it. For the start, you can try to use the snippet which is geared toward someone whose workflow is mostly selecting the active artboard and running a script and where the "Active Layer" is indeed active - or in other words the user is responsible for having the right artboard/layer targeted.

In the modern versions of Illustrator they have fixed the action-memory issue and now it's possible to add reliable F-key shortcuts by playing scripts via an Illustrator action.

Here's the script:

```
#target illustrator
function test(){
    if (app.documents.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var newText = doc.activeLayer.textFrames.add();
    var idx = doc.artboards.getActiveArtboardIndex();
    var currentArtboard = doc.artboards[idx];
    newText.contents = currentArtboard.name;
    newText.top = currentArtboard.artboardRect[1] + 10;
    newText.left = currentArtboard.artboardRect[0] + 10;
    newText.textRange.characterAttributes.size = 20;
};
test();
```

Comment: It looks good for start... I want to ask; is it possible to make active first artboard, adding text and going to next one?

Comment: Sure, but I do not really understand: you want to go to first artboard, place text and then go to 2nd artboard every time? Only those 2 artboards and only text on 1st artboard?

Comment: In a short description, every artboard in doc. have a name on them!

Comment: Is it possible to alter this script to add the text to multiple artboards at once?